# swift - How to give and parse data from swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, sockets, nsstream

I'm a socket project in swift. I try to give data that are `JSON` and Parse them but i have two problem:

1- when I received data are incomplete and return nil value for some bytes.

2- I don't know when The receiving data ends. I receive data in `NSSTreamEvent.hasBytesAvailable` but never run the `NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered` and after some moments the code was error and app crashed.

3- My socket 2 times open while I call them 1 time...

There is my code :

```
import Foundation


class SocketManager : NSObject , NSStreamDelegate {

let ip = "192.168.1.12"
let port = 6969
let introduceStr = ["Type" : 4 , "MobileID" : 2 , "Introduce" : ["ExKey" : 123]]
let jsonParser = JsonMaker()  // This is a class for convert string to json

var inputStream : NSInputStream?
var outputStream : NSOutputStream?
var openedSocket = Int()
var total = NSString()

override init() {
    openedSocket = 0
}

func openSocket() {
    NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(ip, port: port, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
    let inputStatus : NSStreamStatus = (inputStream?.streamStatus)!
    let outputStatus : NSStreamStatus = (outputStream?.streamStatus)!

    if inputStatus != NSStreamStatus.Reading && inputStatus != NSStreamStatus.Open && inputStatus != NSStreamStatus.Opening && outputStatus != NSStreamStatus.Writing && outputStatus != NSStreamStatus.Open && outputStatus != NSStreamStatus.Opening {

        inputStream?.delegate = self
        outputStream?.delegate = self

        inputStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        inputStream?.open()
        outputStream?.open()

    }
}

func tryOpen() {

    inputStream?.close()
    outputStream?.close()

    inputStream?.removeFromRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream?.removeFromRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    performSelector("openSocket", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 5)
}

func closeSocket() {

    inputStream?.removeFromRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream?.removeFromRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    inputStream?.close()
    outputStream?.close()

    performSelector("openSocket", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 15)
}

func getData(aStream : NSStream) {
    if (aStream == inputStream) {
        let MAXSIZE = 1024 * 8
        var allLength = Int()
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: MAXSIZE , repeatedValue: 0)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            while self.inputStream?.hasBytesAvailable == true {
                let readBytes = self.inputStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: sizeofValue(buffer))
                allLength += readBytes!
                if readBytes > 0 {
                    let data : NSData = NSData(bytes: &buffer, length: sizeofValue(buffer))
                    if let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.total = (self.total as String) + (str as String)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func sendData(message : NSString ) -> Int{
    if openedSocket == 0 {
        return -1
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
        let data : NSData = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: (data.length), repeatedValue: 0)
        data.getBytes(&buffer, length: buffer.count)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.outputStream!.write(&buffer, maxLength: (data.length))
            })

        })
        return 1
    }
}

func introduce() {
    if openedSocket == 1{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            let str = self.jsonParser.dictionaryToJson(self.introduceStr)
            let data : NSData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            var buffer = [UInt8](count: (data.length), repeatedValue: 0)
            data.getBytes(&buffer, length: buffer.count)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.outputStream!.write(&buffer, maxLength: (data.length))
                print("the output introducing is finised")
            })
        })
    } else {
        tryOpen()
    }
}

func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
    switch eventCode {
    case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred :
        print("This is the Errorrr")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted :
        openedSocket = 1
        performSelector("introduce", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable :
        getData(aStream)
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered :
        print(total)
        break
    default :
        break
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988784/swift-how-to-fix-the-issue-of-converting-data-to-utf-8-string ?

Comment: You should take a look at Asyncsocket for iOS. Great library with rich documentation when you find the right website.